# Power series for differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The idea is to solve the differential equation $y'=x^2y$ by power series.

it is easy to arrive at the expression $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left((n+1)c_{n+1}-c_nx^2\right)x^n=0$ and therefore $c_{n+1}=\frac{c_nx^2}{n+1}$, then

$y=\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}c_nx^n=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\cdots=c_0+c_0\frac{x^3}{1!}+c_0\frac{x^6}{2!}+\cdots=c_0\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^{3n}}{n!}$

but the real solution of the differential equation is $c_0e^{x^3/3}=c_0\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^{3n}}{3^n n!}$.

The truth I have not been able to get the factor $\frac{1}{3^n}$. I appreciate the help you can give me

Comment: $c_{n+1}=\frac{c_nx^2}{n+1}$ is not correct.

Comment: I think the same, that's why it doesn't give me the correct answer, but I don't see another option

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The coefficient of $x^{n}$ is $(n+1)c_{n+1}-c_{n-2}$. You have to equate this to $0$.

Comment: Thanks Kavi, so if you give me the answer, but I have a doubt, if the counter starts from $n = 0$, but does $c_{-2}$ make sense?

Comment: You have to consider the coefficients of $x^{0}$ and $x^{1}$ separately.